# Is there a quick way to get to the Control Panel in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, shortcuts, control-panel

Obviously in all previous versions of Windows you could simply click START and then select "Control Panel" to get to it, but on **Windows 8** there is no such option.

Is there an easy way to quickly get to it without having to press <kbd>WIN</kbd>, type "Control Panel", and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Win+I is standard way to open an app's settings panel, on desktop that will bring up a panel with *Control Panel* and *Personalization* as options. So this works for desktop only, but is a nice shortcut to use in apps as well.

Or you can do <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then press <kbd>P</kbd>. P as in Control P̲anel. This works everywhere. When pressing Win+X, notice the underline of some of the letters. Pressing the underlined letter will open up the belonging option.

Comment: These are great ones!

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Answer (score 7):

Yes! Simply move the mouse to the BOTTOM LEFT corner and RIGHT CLICK.

This opens the following useful menu:

[image]

Then select Control Panel!

(Alternatively you can press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to see the same menu.)

Answer (score 1):

It's in the Settings charm. In two clicks:

1. One of the right hot corners
2. Settings
3. Control Panel

This only works on the Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to get to options in the control panel is to use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and search for the setting I want to change. Much easier than navigating through the categories!

Answer (score 1):

**Start Control Panel from File Explorer**.

Go to *This PC* and then to the *Computer tab* on the ribbon as shown below:

[image]

There you will find the *Open Control Panel* shortcut.